# Logging an object with a representation that uses an asyncio event loop thread halts the script

Tags: python, multithreading, python-asyncio, python-logging

I have been trying to use the python *websockets* library to create a client for a websocket server and came across a bug I haven't been able to fix.

When logging the object that uses the *asyncio* library, the script just halts for seemingly no reason.

It isn't something critical, but it is bothering me and I don't want this to cause problems down the road.

Here is an example code that reproduces this:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import asyncio
import logging

from threading import Thread

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class Main(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self, daemon=True)
        self.loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        self.running = True
        logger.debug("Init")

    def run(self):
        """ Starts the main loop in the thread """
        logger.debug("Thread Started")
        asyncio.set_event_loop(self.loop)
        # self.main_task = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(
        #     self._mainloop(), self.loop)
        # self.loop.run_forever()
        self.loop.run_until_complete(self._mainloop())
        logger.debug("Thread Finished")

    async def _mainloop(self):
        """ Async main loop """
        while self.running:
            await self.wait(0.1, "_mainloop")
            logger.debug("Test loop")

    async def wait(self, t, text):
        """ Example async function """
        logger.debug("Wait... %s", text)
        await asyncio.sleep(t)
        logger.debug("Wait ok %s", text)
        return "Main object"

    def __repr__(self):
        """ Uses an async function to get the repr """
        fut = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(
            self.wait(0, "__repr__"), self.loop)
        return fut.result()

    def close(self):
        """ Waits for the main loop to end """
        logger.debug("Closing...")
        self.running = False
        self.join()
        # self.main_task.result()
        logger.debug("Closing ok")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    FORMAT = '%(name)-8s %(threadName)-10s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s'
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format=FORMAT)

    logger.info("Start")

    m = Main()
    m.start()

    logger.info("1 %s", repr(m))  # Works fine
    logger.info("2 %s", str(m))   # Works fine
    logger.info("3 %s" % m)       # Works fine
    logger.info("4 %s", m)        # Halts
    logger.info(str(m))           # Works fine
    logger.info(m)                # Also halts

    m.close()

    logger.info("End")
```

Output up to the halting point:

```
__main__ MainThread INFO     Start
asyncio  MainThread DEBUG    Using proactor: IocpProactor
__main__ MainThread DEBUG    Init
__main__ Thread-1   DEBUG    Thread Started
__main__ Thread-1   DEBUG    Wait... _mainloop
__main__ Thread-1   DEBUG    Wait... __repr__
__main__ Thread-1   DEBUG    Wait ok __repr__
__main__ MainThread INFO     1 Main object
__main__ Thread-1   DEBUG    Wait... __repr__
__main__ Thread-1   DEBUG    Wait ok __repr__
__main__ MainThread INFO     2 Main object
__main__ Thread-1   DEBUG    Wait... __repr__
__main__ Thread-1   DEBUG    Wait ok __repr__
__main__ MainThread INFO     3 Main object
```

With the two blocking lines commented, the script continues:

```
__main__ MainThread INFO     3 Main object
__main__ MainThread DEBUG    Closing...
__main__ Thread-1   DEBUG    Wait ok _mainloop
__main__ Thread-1   DEBUG    Test loop
__main__ Thread-1   DEBUG    Thread Finished
__main__ MainThread DEBUG    Closing ok
__main__ MainThread INFO     End
```

Looking into the logging source code, I haven't been able to find something that could explain this.
https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/0bc17658f5724ce60c3f75acc01e7526f1720efe/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L365-L368

I have tried different methods of creating the asyncio event loop, but it didn't make any difference.

Is there some problem with my code? Is this a correct way to use asyncio and threading?

I am using Python 3.9.6 and Logging 0.5.1.2 if that helps.

Comment: Maybe the problem is related to the locks in the Handlers handle method: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2d11797c81be3ae776e418a5ba507098356d357c/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L939